# Adding and Removing Classes on click with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, navigation

So in my rails app, I am trying to have it so that when when a user clicks a link in a menu, that link becomes underlined to indicate it is the current page. I have the basic set up down with javascript and css but I am having trouble getting the `addClass()` and `removeClass()` functions working.

Right now, the `active` link underlines fine, however when the other link is clicked, the active class doesn't transfer (although the link seems to flicker). Any help would be much appreciated!

**The Menu HTML**

```
<div id="collective_tabs">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <%= link_to 'Projects', collective_projects_path(@collective) %>
    </li>
    <li>
      <%= link_to 'Members', collective_members_path(@collective) class: 'active' %>
    </li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require messages
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#collective_tabs li a').on('click', function(){
        $('li a.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works perfectly here:

http://jsfiddle.net/kez5zwgq/

Make sure you have your "a" tags defined in your HTML ;)

HTML

```
<div id="collective_tabs">
 <ul>
   <li>
    <a>potato</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a class="active">tomato</a>
   </li>
 <ul>
</div>
```

You might want to consider using the following CSS:

CSS

```
.active {
   text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Hmm. Makes me think that this problem is with turbolinks integration. I'm assuming there is no way to test that with jsfiddle?

Comment: Check first if "turbolinks" is generating the proper HTML output

Comment: Okay you were right, it was all good. The reason I couldn't get it working was my links were not using ajax and thus clicking one refreshed the menu. As a result, 'members' was always active cause that was default. Face palm.